# Wordpress change contact form 7 html output

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7, contact-form

I am looking got change the output HTML of some of the elements, especially response and checkbox

for example the function wpcf7_checkbox_form_tag_handler I want to change the output of the item

```
$item = sprintf('<input %2$s /><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">%1$s</span>', esc_html( $label ), $item_atts)
```

to

```
$item = sprintf('<input %2$s class="form-check-input" /><label class="wpcf7-list-item-label" class="form-check-label">%1$s</label>', esc_html( $label ), $item_atts)
```

Is this possible with str_replace? I have tried but cannot get it to work.

I would also like to add an id=”” to the input and a for=”” to the label but I expect that to be harder.

With the response output I want to add a close button and I have tried this code

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7-response-output', 'wpcf7_custom_reponse_html', 99, 1 );
function wpcf7_custom_reponse_html( $html ) {
    $html = str_replace( '<div %1$s>%2$s</div>', '<div %1$s>%2$s<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>', $html );
    return $html;
}
```

But this does not work.

Is there any way to edit the output HTML of Contact Form 7?

Thanks

Comment: There is no hook named `wpcf7-response-output` so you can't do this.  Make your own form tag if that's what you need.

Comment: The only way to customise the HTML of a form field is to [create your own form tag](https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/).

Comment: Prior to CF7 v5.4 it was possible to add html to the response output, but this is no longer possible, several issues ([here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/issues/396) and [here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/issues/345)) has been raised on the CF7 github repo to fix this, but the author is notoriously uncooperative.